# How to write .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I installed a online website onto my ubuntu machine for development purposes.

Everything is working except for one section of the site.  When I point the browser to `http://localhost.000-wordpress.co/app` I get the below error in my apache2 error log:

```
[Fri Jan 17 16:57:03 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/app, referer: http://localhost.000-wordpress/
```

The server is looking for the app folder in the wrong location on my file system.  So I have created a .htaccess file but I don't know how to write a rewrite rule for this.

How should I code a rewrite rule to tell the server to go to `/home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app` instead of `/var/www/app`?

This is my **.htaccess file:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### Update

After following Covner's advice I updated my `apache2.conf` file with:

```
Alias /app /home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app
<Directory /home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app>
Order deny,allow
</Directory>
```

But this has thrown back two different errors:

```
[Sat Jan 18 23:35:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/../vendors/yii/framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/index.php on line 12, referer: http://localhost.000-wordpress/

[Sat Jan 18 23:35:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/../vendors/yii/framework/yii.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/index.php on line 12, referer: http://localhost.000-wordpress/
```

Comment: Question is bit confusing , could you clear a bit with pic ?

Comment: @rossmc: What is location of this wordpress .htaccess? Is WP working for you at present?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do anything in htaccess, just use the normal configuration file (they're all created equal)

```
Alias /app /home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app
<Directory /home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app>
Order deny,allow
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you Covener,  I added that code to the bottom of my `apache2.conf` file.  I get two new errors now, I've updated my question.  Do you mind having a look?  I'd appreciate your help.